# Selenium - pause, then download file

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with Chrome and Python for web scraping. I need to download a PDF - the url in question shows a loading page for several seconds, the uses JavaScript to load the PDF into the viewer.

Manually, I can handle this by waiting until the PDF is loaded into the viewer, and clicking the "Save Page As" button. But Chrome wants to initiate a download as soon as the page appears. How can I have Selenium wait until the PDF is available, and then initiate a download?